# Extending a JFrame (empty window error)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, paintcomponent

I'm doing a project that does the following in a nutshell:

1. reads integers from a file
2. stores them in an array
3. creates a bargraph of the numbers with an average line
4. the numbers above average go up, the numbers below go down (both are also different colors)

It compiles correctly, the JFrame window pops up, but no data is printed out. It's just an empty window.

Here is my code:

```
package basicgraphicstester;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class BasicGraphicsTester extends JFrame {
    private Image fImageBuffer;
    private Insets fInsets;
    private Graphics g;
    private static final int WIDTH = 800, HEIGHT = 600;
    private static final Color OVER_AVERAGE = Color.blue, 
        UNDER_AVERAGE = Color.red;
    int[] data;


public BasicGraphicsTester() throws FileNotFoundException
{   ReadInputData();
    addWindowListener(new WindowCloser());
    setVisible(true);
    fInsets = getInsets();
    setSize(WIDTH + fInsets.left + fInsets.right, HEIGHT + fInsets.top +fInsets.bottom);
    setTitle("Bar Graph");
    setResizable(false);
    if (((fImageBuffer = createImage(WIDTH, HEIGHT)) != null) &&
        ((g = fImageBuffer.getGraphics()) != null)) Run();
    else System.exit(1);
}

class WindowCloser extends WindowAdapter
{   public void WindowClosing(WindowEvent e )
    {   System.exit(0); }   
}

private void Run()
{   DrawAverageLine();
    DrawBars();

}


private void DrawBars() 
{   
    double arrayAverage = arrayAverage(data);
    int average = averageLine(data);
    int max = getMaxValue(data);
    int min = getMinValue(data);
    int barWidth = 57;
    double barHeight;

    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    barHeight = (600 * (max - data[i]))/(max - min);
    if (data[i] > average) {
        g.setColor(OVER_AVERAGE);
        g.fillRect((int)barWidth * i, (int)barHeight, (int)barWidth, 
            (average - (int)barHeight));
    }
    else if (barHeight == average) {
        g.setColor(Color.green);
        g.fillRect((int)barWidth * i, average, (int)barWidth, 0);
    }
    else {
        g.setColor(UNDER_AVERAGE);
        g.fillRect((int)barWidth * i, average, (int)barWidth, 
            ((int)barHeight - average));
    repaint();
    }

    } //for loop
} //DrawBar

private void DrawAverageLine() 
{   
    int average = averageLine(data);
    g.drawLine(0, average, 800, average);
}


public static int getMaxValue(int[] data) {  
    int maxValue = data[0];  
    for (int i=1;i < data.length;i++) {  
        if (data[i] > maxValue)  
            maxValue = data[i];  
    }  
    return maxValue;  
   }

public static int getMinValue(int[] data) {
    int minValue = data[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < data.length; i++) {
        if (data[i] < minValue) 
           minValue = data[i];
    }
    return minValue;
}

public static double arrayAverage(int[] data) {
    double result = 0.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        result = result + data[i];
    }
    result = result/data.length;
    return result;
    }

    public static int averageLine (int[] data) {
    int max = getMaxValue(data);
    int min = getMinValue(data);
    return (HEIGHT * max - (int)arrayAverage(data)) / (max - min);
    }

    public void paint( Graphics g)
    {   if (fImageBuffer != null )
        g.drawImage(fImageBuffer, fInsets.left, fInsets.top, null);

    }

    public void ReadInputData() throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {Scanner readFile = new Scanner(new File("BarChart.data"));
            data = new int [13];
            for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
                data[i] = readFile.nextInt();

        } //try

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }

    } // ReadInputData

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {

    new BasicGraphicsTester();
}


}
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

A `JFrame` is an empty frame. You need to put a `JPanel` inside your frame, and override the latter's `paintComponent()` method in order to render your data on screen.

Answer (score 2):

This is not how you do graphics or drawing with Swing, and I'd be interested to see what tutorial you've read recommends you to get the Graphics object as you're doing. Instead you should draw in the `paintComponent(...)` method of a class that extends JComponent such as a JPanel, using the Graphics instance provided as a parameter by the JVM, and then add this component to your JFrame. You will want to read the [painting in Swing tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) which is part of the standard Swing tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to draw right into the JFrame you still have to override ContentPane's paint, not JFrame's paint method AFAIK.
And yes, a better way would be to implement your own component (for example by extending JPanel) and place it inside the JFrame (remember it has to be placed in ContentPane).

Check JFrame javadocs about ContentPane.

Comment: There is no such beast as "ContentPane". Yes, top level windows hold containers which are called its contentPane, but there is no Java class of this name. You may be referring to JComponents or JPanels as the other answers already allude to.

Comment: It's a Container. But it's not just any container. Check JFrame.getContentPane() method.
I don't understand why you're so picky - I never said there's a class called ContentPane. I only mentioned there's a "thing" called ContentPane - and yes, there is, though Class-wise it's a special instance of Container.

Comment: Compiler's are picky. If I read your answer and tried to create a `new ContentPane()`, I know what the compiler would tell me.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels He refers to `JRootPane`.

Answer (score 0):

I recently wrote something similar in JavaFX using the BarGraph component.  I'll post the source code if it would be helpful, but maybe you need to use swing and the point of your project is to make your own bar graph. 
View my [javafx bar graph](http://mathteamhosting.com/teachers/javaFX/ProbabilityGame.html)